# Access 2013 Multiple Columns into Rows

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Ok I am using Access 2013 and have a continuous form using a flat table with the following fields:

```
OrderDate \ Ref \ ItemSize1 \ ItemSize 2 \ ItemSize 3 \ Qty 1 \ Qty 2 \ Qty 3
```

So eg data would look this:

```
09/06/15  \ PO123 \ ABC_S   \     ABC_M   \    ABC_L   \  2    \ 6     \ 8
09/06/15 \ PO123 \ XYZ_8     \   XYZ_10   \    XYZ_12  \ 3     \ 2     \  7
```

However, I'm building a file for export that is needed in this format;

```
OrderDate \ Ref \ Item \ Qty
```

So the result data would look like this:

```
09/06/15 \ PO123 \ ABC_S \ 2
09/06/15 \ PO123 \ ABC_M \ 6
09/06/12 \ PO123 \ ABC_L \ 8
```

and so on....
Points to note:

- Item Size 1 uses the qty from qty 1, item size 2 uses qty etc
- I am only interested where items sizes have a qty.  So if ItemSize 2 had no qty in Qty 2, I would need to miss it out

I have tried a Union query but for some reason it does not sort the size.  The result file needs to have the items in order of size (ItemSize1, ItemSize2 etc)

What other way is there in Access to achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

Michael

Comment: "The other way" would be to normalize your table. A product table, An Invoice table, an Invoice_products table

Comment: in what way did the union not work? It should work without a problem!

Comment: The usual way is with the use of VBA ...maybe a sample can be helpful

Comment: Yes normalisation would be the answer but it is a little too late for that.  The union did not sort the data.  When it is exported it needs to be in the order e.g. size 1, size 2 etc.  For some reason the Union did not do this

Comment: Have you tried sorting it just afterwards? Create the union of (select the first) and (select the second) and (select the third) and then sort that resulting union

Comment: It needs to be the actual order of the fields though.  ItemSize1 needs to be appended then ItemSzie2 etc.  If I just sort the data, it would be wrong.

Comment: Simply put I need to append the rows horizontally not vertically.  Would an array achieve this?

Comment: Can you please show that union query? should not be too hard to adapt it to what you want!

Comment: SELECT tmpTEST.S1 FROM tmpTEST
UNION
SELECT tmpTEST.S2 FROM tmpTEST
UNION
SELECT tmpTEST.S3 FROM tmpTEST
UNION
SELECT tmpTEST.S4 FROM tmpTEST

Comment: S1 is the size.  It can go up to S15 but I only used 3 in the initial example

Comment: And that mixes up the results from the different unions?

Comment: yes.  I need the results to be in order they are append reading from left-to-right.  So what ever is in size 1, then size 2, then size 3 etc....

Comment: I am still not sure what exactly you want: All the 1s, then all the 2s, then all the 3s OR 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, etc.?

Comment: @Michael push. What is the desired output order?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like the following:

```sql
SELECT UnionQueries.val FROM (
  SELECT tmpTEST.Ref as ref, tmpTEST.S1 as val, 1 as col FROM tmpTEST UNION 
  SELECT tmpTEST.Ref as ref, tmpTEST.S2 as val, 2 as col FROM tmpTEST UNION 
  SELECT tmpTEST.Ref as ref, tmpTEST.S3 as val, 3 as col FROM tmpTEST UNION 
  SELECT tmpTEST.Ref as ref, tmpTEST.S4 as val, 4 as col FROM tmpTEST) AS UnionQueries 
ORDER BY UnionQueries.ref, UnionQueries.col ASC
```

Comment: Ok, that is a step forward, thanks.  However it is grouping the items so the output looks like this

Comment: ABC_S

XYZ_S

ABC_M

XYZ_M

Comment: There is supposed to be a return between each one but the page is not displaying them

Comment: @Michael you might want to include the expected behavirou in your question: where should the XYZ_ values be

Comment: Unless I email you a screenshot?

Comment: no need for email, just include an image to your question or upload on imgur and post it as comment

Comment: How do I insert an image that I have saved locally?

Comment: I will take a further look in a a little bit more than one hour - have to work right now

Comment: @Michael i changed the code, maybe that is what you want

Comment: Its ok, I managed a work around.  Every item has a predefined sequence number, so I have brought that in and sorted by that, it is now working.  Thank you though for taking the time to help, it is appreciated.

Comment: is there some way I can still add a badge or something to your profile?

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with krish, your solution is to make the data structure more resilient.

**The real Solution**: (Can be improved a lot)

First create the two tables, `Products` and `Invoice`.

`````````
Products
````````
productID - AutoNumber (PK)
productCategory - Text
productSize - Text

Invoice
```````
invoiceID - AutoNumber (PK)
invoiceDate - DateT/Time
productID - Number (FK)
invoiceQuantity - Number
`````````

Now the relationship between `Products` and `Invoice` is One to Many, where one product can have many Invoices. Example, one Tee Shirt for one sizes/color could have many orders.

Now the Products table will have the information of the products that you have available in your Database. Some sample would be.

```
productID   |   productCategory |   productSize
------------+-------------------+---------------
1           |   Tee Shirt       |   S
2           |   Tee Shirt       |   M
3           |   Polo            |   L
4           |   Vest            |   S
5           |   Vest            |   M
```

Now the Invoice table should have the order for a particular product of particular size.

```
invoiceID   |   invoiceDate |   productID   |   invoiceQuantity
------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------
1           |   09/06/2015  |   1           |   10
2           |   09/06/2015  |   2           |   5
3           |   09/06/2015  |   3           |   10
4           |   09/06/2015  |   5           |   3
```

Now, once the data is transformed into the right structure, your Query would simply be.

```
SELECT
    productCategory,
    productSize,
    invoiceDate,
    invoiceQuantity
FROM
    Products 
    INNER JOIN
    Invoice
    ON 
    Products.productID = Invoice.productID
```

Your result set would be,

```
productCategory |   productSize |   invoiceDate |   invoiceQuantity
----------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------
Tee Shirt       |   S           |   09/06/2015  |   10
Tee Shirt       |   M           |   09/06/2015  |   5
Polo            |   L           |   09/06/2015  |   10
Vest            |   M           |   09/06/2015  |   3
```

Now, you should be able to get your head around, how simple data restructuring could make your queries so simple and easy to implement.

**The temporary fix**

Although it pains for me to tell you you should restructure your tables, does not mean that you cannot achieve what you want. Although the solution would work, and might even seem OK. It actually is not. There is too much memory involved, efficiency is poor. You create and drop records, constantly upsize your DB. so many disadvantages, but to hold things together.

```
Public Sub createTempForm()
    Dim sqlStr As String
    Dim tmpRS As DAO.Recordset, tmpRS2 As DAO.Recordset, tmpDB As DAO.Database

    Set tmpDB = CurrentDB()
    sqlStr = "SELECT OrderDate, Ref, ItemSize1, ItemSize2, ItemSize3, Qty1, Qty2, Qty3 " & _
             "FROM yourTableName"

    Set tmpRS = tmpDB.OpenRecordset(sqlStr)

    tmpDB.Execute "DELETE * FROM tmpTbl"

    'Make sure this table - tmpTbl, is created (just the skeleton, data will be added every time you run this query.)
    Set tmpRS2 = tmpDB.OpenRecordset("tmpTbl")

    Do While Not tmpRS.EOF
        'Go through all records to create the data you wish to see. 
        With tmpRS2
            'This will add as many records to the tmpTbl
            For iCtr = 1 to 3
                If Len(tmpRS.Fields("ItemSize" & iCtr) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
                    'Create a record only if the fields are not null.
                    .AddNew
                    .Fields("OrderDate") = tmpRS.Fields("OrderDate")
                    .Fields("Ref") = tmpRS.Fields("Ref")
                    .Fields("Item") = .Fields("ItemSize" & iCtr)
                    .Fields("Qty") = .Fields("Qty" & iCtr)
                    .Update
                End If
            Next
            tmpRS.MoveNext
        End With
    Loop

    Set tmpRS = Nothing
    Set tmpDB = Nothing

    'This report should be based on the tmpTbl. 
    DoCmd.OpenReport "yourReportName"

    'If you prefer to Export the table as Excel file, you are welcome to do so. Saves designing report. 
    'DoCmd.Outputto acOutputTable, "tmpTbl", acFormatXLS, "C:\testData.xls"
End Sub
```

Now the reason I have used VBA as opposed to luk2302's UNION query is because, with a little modification, the above query could actually be used to transform your flat table data into the structure you should have.

So have a think about it, I am sure you will never ever regret it. Good luck !